# Authentication problem between ASP.NET 4.8 auth and .NET Core 6.0 identity auth

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, .net-core

I have 2 websites that use the same SQL Server database.

Website A is an ASP.NET site built on the .NET framework 4.8 and uses ASP.NET authentication, and has been in use for many years.

Website B is a new website built on ASP.NET Core 6.0 and uses ASP.NET Core identity authentication.

Both websites share the same SQL Server database and the same `aspnet` tables including `AspNetUsers` used for authentication.

Both websites use their default password hashing algorithm, so I assume they're the same.

A user has been logging into website A with these creds:

```
user@ex.com
Abcd123!
```

When the user logs into website B using the same creds, the authentication is successful, but something happens to the user data in the `AspNetUsers` table, so next time when the user logs back into website A, the authentication fails.

It seems that website B and ASP.NET Core Identity changes the user data in such a way the .NET 4.8 authentication can not be used any more.

This is the ASP.NET Core 6.0 code used in website B for authentication:

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public HomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IEmailSender emailSender)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _emailSender = emailSender;
}
```

... in another method

```
var userResult = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(login.UserName);
```

I think this is the line where the problem begins.

Below is the .NET 4.8 code used in website A for authentication:

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

... in another method

```
ApplicationUser result = await UserManager.FindAsync(userName, password);
```

Why does .NET Core 6.0 Identity cause a problem for .NET 4.8 authentication?

And what can I do so both websites can authenticate to the same `AspNetUsers` table?

Thank you.